# how to throw error/exception from swift singleton init

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

In my custom swift framework I have a singleton class which end user will be using. The singleton init() does lots of work for which I want to throw error if anything goes wrong during initialisation.

### mySingleton.swift

```
public class mySingleton: NSObject {
    .......
    public static let sharedInstance = mySingleton(singleton : true)
    ....
}

private override convenience init() {
    assertionFailure( "Please use sharedInstance" )
    self.init(singleton : false)
}

private init(singleton: true) {
    super.init()

    //Other class objects init() etc.

   //Some other processing etc.

}
```

### Framework users:

```
//Initialise framework
mySingleton.sharedInstance
```

What would be the best way to throw error/exception to the end user during mySingleTon init process.

Comment: Note: you will throw an *error*, not an exception. Exceptions are programmer's responsibility to avoid, they cannot be caught with Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Variant with Implicitly Unwrapped value:

```
public class MySingleton: NSObject {

    private static var _sharedInstance: MySingleton!

    public static var sharedInstance: MySingleton! {

        if _sharedInstance == nil {

            let instance = MySingleton()

            if let error = instance.initializationError {

                //log an error
                print("An error occured during singleton object instantiation: \(error)")
                return nil
            }

            _sharedInstance = instance
        }

        return _sharedInstance
    }

    var initializationError: ErrorType?

    private override init() {

        super.init()

        //Other class objects init() etc.

        //Some other processing etc.

        do {
            try initialize()
        } catch {
            initializationError = error
        }
    }

    private func initialize() throws {

        throw NSError(domain: "my.error", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Implemented this. Now where ever I have accessed a mySingleton public variable like --     "mySingleTon.sharedInstance().pubVar"     the compiler is showing error: "Call can throw error, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled."  This will be burden to write do, try, catch for every access of variables. Can we avoid this anyway...

Comment: @SaffronState There are options. The most convenient variant is to return Implicitly Unwrapped variable (MySingleton!). I have updated the answer. If that's not suitable too we can cosider returning just optional MySingleton? The second variant is not such comfortable but more safe as user should explicitly unwrap returned value.

Comment: The first approach worked and i think thats the better option over the second. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should really, really think about what your intentions are here.

A singleton is created *once* and stays alive for the rest of the application. What is your application going to do if creating the singleton fails? Where I use singletons, they *must* succeed. If they don't, my app cannot run.

If creating the singleton fails, then the best is to produce an assertion that will kill the app. On the other hand, in many problematic situations (missing network connection, for example) creation of the singleton *should not fail*.

Comment: One thing to consider with this answer is unit testing. Say your singleton must load (and hopefully validate) static data from a PLIST. How do you test this without crashing the test? That's a valid scenario for "maybe the singleton will fail". This area is ... fuzzy. It makes proper testing challenging.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw an error or make an init fail pertaining to certain conditions ,use failable initialisers

```
struct Animal {
    let species: String
    init?(species: String) {
    if species.isEmpty { return nil }
      self.species = species
    }
}
```

Hope this should help